# Why is foundation 6 JS file so large?

Tags: javascript, gulp, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I'm currently using foundation 6 for sites.

JS is minified using the built-in version of Gulp:

```
function javascript() {
  return gulp.src(PATHS.javascript)
    .pipe($.sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe($.babel())
    .pipe($.concat('app.js'))
    .pipe($.if(PRODUCTION, $.uglify()
    .on('error', e => { console.log(e); })
    ))
    .pipe($.if(!PRODUCTION, $.sourcemaps.write()))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(PATHS.dist + '/assets/js'));
}
```

The overall size of these scripts on my disk is **249 ko**.

I tried this command:

```
foundation watch --production
```

Once compiled with GULP, I get **1 795 ko**!

I just don't understand what's going on.

Would you have any clues to help me on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found out the command to generate a proper production version.

```
foundation build
```